# numpy structured array no shape information?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Why is the shape of a single row  numpy structured array not defined ( '()') and whats the common "workaround"?

```
import io
fileWrapper = io.StringIO("-0.09469 0.032987 0.061009 0.0588")

a =np.loadtxt(fileWrapper,dtype=np.dtype([('min', (float,2) ), ('max',(float,2) )]), delimiter= " ", comments="#");
print(np.shape(a), a)
```

**Output:** () ([-0.09469, 0.032987], [0.061009, 0.0588])

Comment: whats the result of `print a` after `a =np.loadtxt`

Comment: added the output above

Comment: this some how inconsistent wrong behaviour makes code syntax mad, i.e. distinguish between single row arrays or bigger ones

Comment: `()` is shape information - for a single element 0d array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer*: Add the argument `ndmin=1` to the `loadtxt` call.

*Long answer*:

The shape is `()` for the same reason that reading a single floating point value with `loadtxt` returns an array with shape `()`:

```
In [43]: a = np.loadtxt(['1.0'])

In [44]: a.shape
Out[44]: ()

In [45]: a
Out[45]: array(1.0)
```

By default, `loadtxt` uses the `squeeze` function to eliminate trivial (i.e. length 1) dimensions in the array that it returns.  In my example above, it means the result is a "scalar array"--an array with shape `()`.

When you give `loadtxt` a structured dtype, the structure defines the fields of a single element of the array.  It is common to think of these fields as "columns", but structured arrays will make more sense if you consistently think of them as what they are: arrays of structures with fields.  If your data file had *two* lines, the array returned by `loadtxt` would be an array with shape `(2,)`.  That is, it is a one-dimensional array with length 2.  Each element of the array is a structure whose fields are defined by the given dtype.  When the input file has only a single line, the array would have shape `(1,)`, but `loadtxt` squeezes that to be a scalar array with shape `()`.

To force `loadtxt` to always return a one-dimensional array, even when there is a single line of data, use the argument `ndmin=1`.

For example, here's a dtype for a structured array:

```
In [58]: dt = np.dtype([('x', np.float64), ('y', np.float64)])
```

Read one line using that dtype.  The result has shape `()`:

```
In [59]: a = np.loadtxt(['1.0 2.0'], dtype=dt)

In [60]: a.shape
Out[60]: ()
```

Use `ndmin=1` to ensure that even an input with a single line results in a one-dimensional array:

```
In [61]: a = np.loadtxt(['1.0 2.0'], dtype=dt, ndmin=1)

In [62]: a.shape
Out[62]: (1,)

In [63]: a
Out[63]: 
array([(1.0, 2.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Comment: very concise answer!!